# Can I tell less to read in a whole stream?

Tags: shell, less

Related to this question: [How can I get file information in 'less' like with 'man'?](https://superuser.com/questions/170572/how-can-i-get-file-information-in-less-like-with-man)

Is there a way to ask less to suck in a whole stream to EOF (or at least to some size limit) so that,  when it's being used to read from a pipe, it can still give location in the prompt as a percentage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass it `+G1G` so that it scrolls to the end (and loads the stream) and then scrolls back to the beginning.